# Is it possible to run Rails console with pager like less?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

I'm using the [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print/) to prettify objects to print.
But when I use it for many objects, I can't see all of them because they are too many to display in terminal scroll.
I would like to use a pager like `less` in rails console. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hirb gem solves just that

```
gem install hirb
```

usage example:

```
irb -rhirb
> Hirb.enable
> (1..1000).to_a
```

after enabling it inside the console, when printing large data, it will automatically pipe it through `less`

It also has a menu creation feature that might be useful for you in those situations. More info [here](http://tagaholic.me/2009/06/19/page-irb-output-and-improve-ri-with-hirb.html)

Answer (score 1):

Give [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) a try. It has many other features that would make your Ruby/Rails programming more fun.